# Truecrypt mount system drive from "outside"

Tags: windows, partitioning, mount, truecrypt

i am trying to mount an encrypted system disk from a Winbuilder Win 8 live disk with Truecrypt 7.1a.

The encrypted disk originally has a 100GB and a 400GB partition, but truecrypts mount dialogue does only show

```
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition1 (100 MB)
\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2 (100 GB)
```

the other partition is not available.

for the first two partitions

```
truecrypt.exe /v \Device\Harddisk0\Partition1 /a /m ro /m sm /p PASSWORD
```

(read-only, pre-boot/system mode) does work, is there any chance to access the 3rd partition, and if so, what am i missing? Can i somehow mount the "whole drive" instead of the single partitions?

Thanks in advance
Seb